# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         s.spriden_id,
         swkadfu.goremal_email_address(spriden_pidm,'TAMU','goremal_email_address') AS email,
         sum(tbraccd_amount) 
from tbraccd
  join spriden s on s.spriden_pidm = tbraccd_pidm
           AND s.spriden_ntyp_code = 'UIN'
           AND s.spriden_change_ind = 'I'
group by spriden_id,swkadfu.goremal_email_address
having sum(tbraccd_amount) >='20000';
```

This query throws an error. Function and group by will not go together?

Comment: Why are you using `DISTINCT` and an aggregation function (`SUM`) together in the same query?

Comment: You cant group by a function.  Try with group by on the field that the function takes.

Comment: @acroyear i sed distinct before trying to use group by .. thanks for pointing that

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the full expression in the `group by`

```
group by spriden_id, wkadfu.goremal_email_address(spriden_pidm,'TAMU','goremal_email_address')
```

Comment: Try a function based index on `wkadfu.goremal_email_address(spriden_pidm,'TAMU','goremal_email_address')`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you missed.

First, a function:

```
SQL> create or replace function goremal (par_deptno in number, par_null in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval dept.dname%type;
  5  begin
  6    select dname into retval
  7      from dept
  8      where deptno = par_deptno;
  9
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

The way to properly call it:

- all columns that aren't aggregated should be

  - in your case, those are `e.ename`, `e.deptno` (which is a parameter to the function; the function itself can, but doesn't have to be part of the `group by` clause; that depends on what result you expect. If you omit the whole function, code will execute)
- `distinct` is not necessary when there's `group by`; won't hurt anything, but won't help either. `GROUP BY` will make sure distinct values are returned
- summary returns a number, so - don't enclose that condition into single quotes, i.e. it should be `>= 20000`, not  `>= '20000'`

so it looks like this:

```
SQL> select e.ename,
  2         goremal(e.deptno, null) as dept_name,
  3         sum(e.sal) sum_sal
  4  from emp e
  5  group by e.ename, e.deptno
  6  having sum(e.sal) > 100;

ENAME      DEPT_NAME          SUM_SAL
---------- --------------- ----------
SMITH      RESEARCH               800
JONES      RESEARCH              2975
FORD       RESEARCH              3000
CLARK      ACCOUNTING            2450
<snip>
```

Your query would then look like this:

```
select s.spriden_id,
       swkadfu.goremal_email_address(spriden_pidm,'TAMU','goremal_email_address') as email,
       sum(tbraccd_amount) 
from tbraccd
  join spriden s on s.spriden_pidm = tbraccd_pidm
           and s.spriden_ntyp_code = 'UIN'
           and s.spriden_change_ind = 'I'
group by spriden_id,
         spriden_pidm
having sum(tbraccd_amount) >= 20000;
```

Comment: thank you for detailing... very helpful.. will try this

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  s.spriden_id, 
  swkadfu.goremal_email_address(
    spriden_pidm, 'TAMU', 'goremal_email_address'
  ) AS email, 
  sum(tbraccd_amount) 
from 
  tbraccd 
  join spriden s on s.spriden_pidm = tbraccd_pidm 
  AND s.spriden_ntyp_code = 'UIN' 
  AND s.spriden_change_ind = 'I' 
group by 
  s.spriden_id, 
  swkadfu.goremal_email_address(
    spriden_pidm, 'TAMU', 'goremal_email_address'
  ) 
having 
  sum(tbraccd_amount) >= '20000';
```

Comment: the syntax is sorta correct, except for those underscores. 
I don't really know what : swkadfu.goremal_email_address(
    spriden_pidm, 'TAMU', 'goremal_email_address'
  ) is supposed to be...